# Why Customer Community Login user doesn't see one Salesforce user but sees another?

Tags: community, sharing, owd

### BACKGROUND

We have a trigger on the FeedItem (Chatter post) which uses a helper class:

```
public without sharing class FeedItemTriggerHelper
{
    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<FeedItem> chatterPosts)
    {
        System.debug([SELECT Id, Email, Name FROM User Where Id = '<user1Id>']);
        System.debug([SELECT Id, Email, Name FROM User Where Id = '<user1Id>']);
    }
}
```

When an external user (assigned to the Customer Community Login license) leaves chatter comment on a record in our Customer Community, the above code executes and `user1` is not visible - the list is empty, and details for `user2` are showed.

This is awkward since both `user1` and `user2` has the same User Licence - Salesforce, assigned to the same role in the role hierarchy. All sharing settings are on the screenshot below:

[image]

I checked manual sharing for both users and didn't see any sharing access.

### QUESTION

As you can see from the code above the `without sharing` keywords were used, but that didn't help. I don't understand why with the `private` OWD for External Sharing, one user is visible, and the other isn't?

Comment: Check if by any chance a [sharing set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5) is configured for enabling this access

Comment: Can you clarify as what do you exactly mean by this -- [*the above code executes and user1 is not visible - the list is empty, and details for user2 are showed*]? Where is `user1` not visible and `user2` visible? Who are `user1` and `user2` in this context?